How to add the plane y = x to a 3D surface plot in Plotly?
I am currently working on a 3D surface plot using Plotly in Python. Below is the code I have so far:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Definition of the domain
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Definition of the function, avoiding division by zero
Z = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 != 0, (X * Y) / (X**2 + Y**2), 0)

# Creation of the interactive graph
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=X, y=Y, colorscale='Viridis')])

# Add title and axis configurations
fig.update_layout(
    title='Interactive graph of f(x, y) = xy / (x^2 + y^2)',
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='X',
        yaxis_title='Y',
        zaxis_title='f(X, Y)'
    ),
)

# Show the graph
fig.show()

I would like to add the plane (y = x) to this plot. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to add this plane to my existing surface plot? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To add '=' to your 3D surface plot in Plotly, you can define a separate surface for this plane and add it to the figure using another 'go.Surface' object.
In Plotly, the Surface plot requires explicit values for  to display a plane. To achieve the = plane across a given  range, we need to set both  and  to represent = over a flat range of .
Here is the new code that I modified,
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Definition of the domain
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Definition of the function, avoiding division by zero
Z = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 != 0, (X * Y) / (X**2 + Y**2), 0)

# Creation of the main surface plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=X, y=Y, colorscale='Viridis')])

# Define the y = x plane
x_plane = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y_plane = x_plane  # y = x
X_plane, Z_plane = np.meshgrid(x_plane, np.linspace(-1, 1, 2))  # Z range can be adjusted as needed
Y_plane = X_plane  # Since y = x

# Add the y = x plane to the plot
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Z_plane, x=X_plane, y=Y_plane, colorscale='Reds', opacity=0.5))

# Add title and axis configurations
fig.update_layout(
    title='3D Surface Plot with Plane y = x',
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='X',
        yaxis_title='Y',
        zaxis_title='f(X, Y)'
    ),
)

# Show the graph
fig.show()

and the output is


Thank you, but your code seems to do the same things as mine; it does not draw any plane

I edited y code, could you please try it?

The thing is, you can't draw a vertical plane defining Z as a function of X and Y, like you did for your other surface. Hence the reason why Busra's code show nothing.
(Think in 2D: you could plot a curve as x=a range, y=f(x). But if you want to add a vertical line to that, you couldn't just do the same, with another f, for the vertical curve)
Fortunately, there is no need for it. Surface doesn't really plot Z=f(x,y) surfaces, but generally speaking plot of bunch of "rectangles" (well, pairs of triangles probably) specified in the form of 3 2D arrays, for x, y and z.
So, exactly like you would plot your vertical line as x=g(y) and y=a range (with g being constant), you can here do the same. For example, have x and z form a meshgrid, and define y=f(x,z)=x
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Definition of the domain
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Definition of the function, avoiding division by zero
Z = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 != 0, (X * Y) / (X**2 + Y**2), 0)

# Creation of the main surface plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=X, y=Y, colorscale='Viridis')])

# Define the plane y = x over the same domain
z_plane = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 100)  # For a flat plane at Z=0 or another value
XY_plane, Z_plane=np.meshgrid(x,z_plane)

# Add the plane to the plot
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Z_plane, x=XY_plane, y=XY_plane, colorscale='Reds', opacity=0.5))

# Add title and axis configurations
fig.update_layout(
    title='3D Surface Plot with Plane y = x',
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='X',
        yaxis_title='Y',
        zaxis_title='f(X, Y)'
    ),
)
fig.show()


Note that I've recycled your x_plane, just to keep it as close as the intended reusage of the domain.
But, since this is a plane (exactly like, still continuing my 2D analogy, you would need y to be a linspace of 100 points to plot a vertical line. x=[0,0], y=[-ymin, ymax] would do), you don't really need to bother plotly with a 100×100 discretized surface.
So
XY_plane, Z_plane=np.meshgrid([-5,5],[Z.min(), Z.max()])

would do the exact same result, with less pain for plotly. Just a set of 2x2 points for x, y and z, defining a single rectangle.
